# Represent in the cartesian plane the inequality $|w-z|<1$ given $z$

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

I know that $A=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:z^3+z^2-3z-6=0\}$.

I found out that the solutions are: $z_1=2, z_2=\frac{-3+\sqrt{3}i}{2}, z_3=\frac{-3-\sqrt{3}i}{2}$.

Now, I have to represent in the cartesian plane $B=\{w\in \mathbb{C}:|w-z|<1, \text{with z} \in A\}$

How do I do that since $w$ can be any complex number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|w-z_0|<1$ is the **interior** of a circle centered at $z_0$ and radius $1$. So for each $z_0 \in A$ you draw such a circle (i.e. 3 circles).

Now assuming that the defining condition for set $B$ is $|w-z|<1$ **for some** $z \in A$, you want the union of these three regions as your set $B$.

Comment: So in this case $B=\{\emptyset\}$?

Comment: @Kevin NO it is the **union** (not intersection) so definitely non-empty. If the defining condition was $|w-z|<1$ **for all** $z \in A$ then it would be the intersection of the three regions and (most likely, I haven't drawn myself) the intersection is $\emptyset$.

Comment: I got it, thank you very much!